# ¿Cómo valido si un número es de tipo flotante?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while, float, iteradores

Quiero valuar que un dato ingresado sea de tipo flotante; de lo contrario, debe enviar un mensaje de error al momento de la ejecución.

Hasta el momento, este es mi último intento realizado:

```
n=[]
i=0
while i<3:
    n.insert(i, input("Mete el numero: "))

    if '.' in n[i]:
        continue
        if i<0 or i>3:
            break
    else:
        print("Tipo de dato erróneo. Debe ingresar un valor de tipo flotante para continuar.")
        i-=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evaluar si un numero es flotante hay que hacer más que evaluar un simple punto. Hay dos formas, una más compleja que es evaluando cada componente de la cadena introducida para verificar si cumple con un flotante. Y la segunda, que no es la más 'linda', pero que es válida, más simple y no te van a mirar feo por usarla: convertir explicitamente la cadena a flotante dentro de un bloque de captura de errores.

```
def is_float(string):
    try:
        num = float(string)
        #num = num if string.find('.') >= 0 else False
    except:
        num = False
    return num
```

Si notas, hay una línea comentada. Si quieres que **obligatoriamente** la persona introduzca un número con punto `'.'` entonces descomenta esa línea. Lo único que hace es que verifica si en la cadena hay un punto, si es así, `num` siguen siendo `num`, de lo contrario cambia a `False`.

En el programa principal

```
n = []
i = 0
while i<3:
    number = is_float(input(f"Mete el numero {i+1}: "))
    if number:
        n.append(number)
        i += 1
    else:
        print("Tipo de dato erróneo.")

print(n)
```